# Need to keep blank field with the data on the table

Tags: php

So I'm trying to have the user update this table, but if the field is left blank i'd like the data to be left alone, not change it to a blank field or null, any ideas?

```
<?
    elseif ($Code == "U")
    {
    $sql = "UPDATE movieDATA SET Name = '$Name', Genre = '$Genre', Starring = '$Starring', Year = '$Year', BoxOffice = '$BoxOffice' where IDNO = '$idno'";
    $result= mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $showresult = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * from movieDATA") or die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error($link));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($showresult))
       {
        echo ("<br> ID = ". $row["IDNO"] . "<br> NAME =  " . $row["Name"] . "<br>");
        echo("Genre = " . $row["Genre"] . "<br> Starring = " . $row["Starring"] . "<br>");
        echo("Year = " . $row["Year"] . "<br> Box Office = " . $row["BoxOffice"] . "<br>");
       }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Not clear your question. Please describe or give desire output.

Comment: I'm updating a table, when the user leaves a field blank, the code will update the table to a blank field, I would like for the table to retain the data it had, and not be overwritten with blank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fields = array(); // Take a blank array of fields and values.
$Name = trim($Name); // Trim the variable, user may add only spaces
$Genre = trim($Genre); // Do this for all variables.
$Starring = trim($Starring);
$Year = trim($Year);
$BoxOffice = trim($BoxOffice);
if (! empty($Name)) { // If user has filled the field, append to array.
$fields[] = "Name = '$Name'";
}
if (! empty($Genre)) {
$fields[] = "Name = '$Genre'";
}
if (! empty($Starring)) {
$fields[] = "Name = '$Starring'";
}
if (! empty($Year)) {
$fields[] = "Name = '$Year'";
}
if (! empty($BoxOffice)) {
$fields[] = "Name = '$BoxOffice'";
}
if (! empty($fields)) { // If the array is not empty, go for Query.
$sql = "UPDATE movieDATA SET "; // If user has not added any field value,
$sql .= implode(', ', $fields); // no SQL Query will be fired.
$sql .= " WHERE IDNO = '$idno'";
}
```

Your requirement:

Not to update the fields which user has left blank.

Solution:

- Add if condition to check if every field is filled up.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this:

```php
$q_set = [];

if (!empty($Name)) {
  $q_set []= "Name = '$Name'";
}
if (!empty($Genre)) {
  $q_set []= "Genre = '$Genre'";
}
/* ... */
if (!empty($q_set)) {
  $sql = "UPDATE movieDATA SET " . implode(',', $q_set)
    . " WHERE IDNO = '$idno'";
}
```

Note, that the variables passed into SQL [should be escaped](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: This seems like the professional thing to do! however this is homework and I can use it. Any way this can be done with simpler code?

Comment: @FagnerSchuindtCaetano, you could collect them in a single line: `foreach (['Name', 'Genre'] as $f) isset(${$f}) and $set []= "$f = '" . ${$f} . "'";`. But it's a really bad code because it's full of assumptions. The code should be simple to read, but not necessarily brief.